# Update Firebase Crash report to Firebase Crashlytics: still on old dashboard

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I upgraded my android application to use Firebase Crashlytics instead of Firebase Crash report following the steps described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting).

And I added this crash test in the application:

```
Button crashButton = new Button(this);
crashButton.setText("Crash!");
crashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Crashlytics.getInstance().crash(); // Force a crash
    }
});
addContentView(crashButton,
               new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I can actually see the crashes generated by Crashlytics on the Firebase dashboard:

[image]

But as you can see this is still using the old Dashboard and when I go to Crashlytics, even after following all the steps described in the documentation, I always have this page: 
[image]

And then:

[image]

And nothing happens.
Is there some more steps which need to be done to make the Firebase crash reporting dashboard be replaced by the Crashlytics dashboard?

Comment: Hey, Paul from Crashlytics here. It looks like the crashes are sent to the Crash Reporting dashboard. Can you confirm if they are sent to the Crashlytics dashboard as well? Thanks!

Comment: Hey! How can I check that? I cannot access to the Crashlytics dashboard..
I use only the Crashlytics class though (Crashlytics.log(), Crashlytics.getInstance().crash(), etc)

Comment: Are you able to go through the flow after clicking "Continue onboarding Crashlytics" and see your crashes there?

Comment: No each time I have the screen leading to the documentation with step 1: Is this app new to Crashlytics? step 2: Install the SDK, step 3: Build and run your app, and get stuck on this page, I have never seen the Crashlytics Dashboard

Comment: (I added the screenshot on the initial post)

Comment: @buser We are seeing the same problem with our app. We are never able to view the Crashlytics Dashboard after following the steps described here. Was there ever a solution to this?

Comment: Did you ever at any time have Fabric.io/Crashlytics installed? I had a reference to keys in my plist, I have an iOS app, that was throwing it off. After I removed the keys everything started working.

Comment: Same is happening on my side @buser and it's a bit frustrating. I think it is uploading successfully to Crashlytics: `I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5B77F22E00B1-0001-77F0-862C6F016FE0`

Answer (score 3):

i have the same problem, with chronology :

- first, my app used crashlytics from fabric
- second, i replace the crashlytics with firebase crash report, but not completely removed
- third, i want to upgrade from firebase crash report to firebase crashlytics, still on old dashboard.

Then i read the documentation :

```
If you're moving to Firebase Crashlytics from Fabric Crashlytics, there are two things to be aware of:

Fabric Beta doesn't currently have a Firebase equivalent. If you'd like to use Beta in your project, keep using Fabric Crashlytics.
If you're upgrading an existing app from Fabric Crashlytics, remove the Fabric API key from your AndroidManifest.xml by deleting the key's meta-data tag, which should include io.fabric.ApiKey and your old Fabric API key.
```

So i remove Fabric API key from my AndroidManifest.xml, then run the app. It works.

Comment: thanks a lot! removing "ApiKey" from Manifest solved my problem :)

Comment: This works for me.
Also make sure you remove all other references to Fabric / Crashlytics from code, manifest and gradle files.   
Then follow the tutorial from start:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0

Comment: Thanks..removing fabric API Key from project worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the dependency for `firebase-crash` from the `build.gradle`; then it reports:

> D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
>
> I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful

then it should only report to `Crashlytics`. also linking the projects in the dashboard is required.

one can also enable/disable the crash reporting in the `Mainfest.xml` with:

```
<!-- <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value=""/> -->
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false"/>
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true"/>
```

removing the old one `Firebase Crash Reporting` library and the old one `Fabric Crashlytics` API key will connect the app to `Firebase Crashlytics`. the iOS client should behave similar... however, when manually migrating, the previous logs may not be retained - in case you need them, better wait for the reporting being migrated. https://medium.com/@bonnell/fabric-and-firebaser-here-16ffb98b5afe